# How do I disable selectRowAtIndexPath when subview is visible

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am writing a "tweetie 2" like swipe functionality, but have run into what I hope is the last stumbling block.

When a user swipes across a table row the "controls" view animates as expected, but when the row is selectd, **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** is fired off.  The desired result is for when the "controls" view is visible to disable the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method or for a lack of a better phrase...stop the responder chain for continuing past the "controls" view.

The uitouch delegate methods are used/being called in the custom uitablviewcell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of logic should do the job here. Let's say you add this property to your UITableViewController subclass:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathForCellInUtilityMode;
```

When the user triggers the cell's utility view, your cell does this:

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [parentViewController.tableView indexPathForCell:self];
parentViewController.indexPathForCellInUtilityMode = cellIndexPath;
```

Then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if ([indexPath compare:indexPathForCellInUtilityMode] != NSOrderedSame) {
//Do whatever you're normally doing in this method.
}
```

So you'll disable selection for the affected cell while still allowing the user to interact with other visible cells.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but how do I set the parentViewController property without alloc/init the RootViewController (which will take place in my custom cell) or is that the expected route?

Comment: No worries. Since you're creating a custom cell subclass, you can easily add a property to it called parentViewController. Make sure the property is assign rather than retain to prevent retain cycles. Then, when the viewController instantiates the cell, set `cell.parentViewController = self;` Make sense?

Comment: @Danilo I think it does.  I am going to come up with some sample code to post this week so that my assumptions can be verified.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

What about setting/unsetting the value of `allowsSelection` in `UITableView` as needed?